# twilio for Python not working on mac

Tags: python, macos, twilio

Im trying to learn Python, but  stumbled across a problem with installing twilio.
I followed all of the steps for installation that i found on the official website but when I type in import twilio in my python 3.4.3 shell it is coming up with following error
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import twilio
ImportError: No module named 'twilio'`

here is what im getting in terminal

```
easy_install twilio
Searching for twilio
Best match: twilio 4.4.0
Processing twilio-4.4.0-py2.7.egg
twilio 4.4.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twilio-4.4.0-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for twilio
Finished processing dependencies for twilio
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You appear to be installing it for Python 2.7 but expecting it to be available in Python 3.4... that won't work!

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There are  few things you can check for when doing that.

- Check to make sure that you don’t have a file named twilio.py; Python will try to load the Twilio library from your twilio.py file instead of from the Twilio library.
- Check which versions of pip and Python you are running with this command in the Terminal:

  which -a python

  which -a pip

`pip` needs to install the Twilio library to a path that your Python executable can read from. Sometimes there will be more than one version of pip, like pip-2.5, pip-2.7 etc. You can find all of them by running `compgen -c | grep pip` (works with Bash on *nix machines). There can also be more than one version of Python, especially if you have Macports or homebrew.

Make sure you have the latest version of pip and of Twilio.

```
pip install --upgrade twilio
```

Also, you seem to be using the wrong shell as you mention you are using Python 3.4.3. You could change your version to 2.7 by running the following:

```
alias python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: i checked and there aren't any other twilio.py files on my mac. when it comes to the versions here is are details about my python `which -a python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python` and when it comes to the pip here is result of `which -a pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip`, results of `compgen -c | grep pip
pip3
pip3.4
pip3
pip3.4
pip
pip2
pip2.7
pip3
pip3.4`

Comment: Updated my response. It's your python version

Comment: so it seems that Twilio doesnt work on 3.4 since when i installed 2.7 it is working fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you, my problem was use file with name twilio.py.